# Diagnosing random, temporary computer "pauses"

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, diagnostic

My computer that I use every day has had the problem for over a year where periodically (between once and six times per day) it will become mostly unresponsive for a short period of time. This is characterized by:

- The mouse cursor moves.
- I can use the window manager (click to foreground a window/app, drag to move windows).
- iTunes music will continue to play (sometimes pausing, presumably when the buffer ran out).
- Asking any application to do most anything will result in that application becoming unresponsive - grey window, spinning cursor. I can't type in Sublime Text editor, I can't load a web page, I can't change volume on the computer using keyboard hardware keys. I can often change the selected message in Outlook, but the Preview pane will not actually load what I have selected.

After about 10-30 seconds everything returns to normal, including processing most queued up actions.

I just reformatted and re-installed the OS from scratch. Re-installed the most common apps, and during installation day noticed it happening. Now, days later, it's still going on.

### Possibly Relevant Details

- Windows 7x64
- On a corporate domain with group policy managed by IT
- Sophos Antivirus (forced by IT, cannot prevent it)
- 8GB RAM; usually no more than 5GB physical in use when this happens
- Three hard drives, each with between 35-80GB free.

  - I ran a disk check on the C: drive, including checking for bad sectors - no issues reported
- I have left Process Explorer running today and after each system pause I frantically scanned through both the system graphs and a few per-process graphs (e.g. Sohpos, iTunes). I have not seen any spikes in CPU or IO when this occurs.
- I almost always have running: MS Outlook, iTunes, Skype, Google Chrome. (Just in case one of these apps might be the culprit.)
- I have two display cards—GeForce GTX 670 & GeForce 9600GS—driving four monitors. Most recent GeForce driver.
- I cannot detect any activity on my part that triggers this. I will often be doing something as simple as typing text in Sublime Text, and have been typing for tens of minutes, when suddenly it will go non-responsive.

Are there any OS-level software issues could cause these sorts or freezes, this mix of working and not? Are any of them ruled out by having re-installed the OS fresh? What diagnostic tools could help to detect these?

Are there any hardware issues that would cause this sort of problem? What tools might I run to test these?

Comment: The AV is one of the likeliest candidates. Do you know when it runs scheduled scans?

Comment: @lzam Looking at scan logs it looks like it turns on-access scanning on for ~3 hours at a time every ~7 hours.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen on my Windows 7 box and in the end it turned out to be a disk that started to have hardware errors.  Strange because the Event Log really did not show anything this drastic happening.  Since the disk eventually died and was replaced the problem has disappeared.

Comment: Good information, thanks. This is what I had assumed it was for years, so I was surprised when the main disk (which is the only spot I assumed could affect it) turned out OK. I'll scan the other two tonight.

Comment: Well, I had done similar scans showing my system disk was OK until the disk died a horrible death.  The pauses and delays were just driving me nuts as I could not determine the cause.

Comment: This was also the case with my mac. See if you can get to the S.M.A.R.T. data for the drive.

Answer (score 0):

- Antivirus might be the culprit.

If you can, boot the system from Safe mode and use it awhile, to see if the random pauses occur.

- Hard drive might be going out.

If you can, boot the system from a Linux live CD of some sort, to see if it behaves better when not loaded/running from the hard drive.

- Could be a firmware issue.  Try updating the BIOS.
- Your system is overheating.
- You have burst caps on your motherboard, esp. if this machine was manufactured before 2008 or so and is a small-form-factor type.